# Not getting Vim to autoload files in ftdetect custom plugin project

Tags: vim

The example I am following is from the book The VimL Primer Chap 4.

In the `ftdetect` dir I have the following line:

```
autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile *.mpdv set filetype=mpdv
```

In a file called mpdv.vim

However this command is not executed when I open a mpdv file.
In .vimrc I have:

```
filetype plugin on
```

The way im loading the plugin is the following:
In ~/.vimrc I have:

```
set exrc
```

This forces vim to load local .vimrc files

Then in my projects pluginfolder i have the follwoing .vimrc

```
set runtimepath+=path/to/my/plugin
```

What can I do the debug why vim is not loading my autocmd when I open a mpdv file?

Comment: I think this autocommand should be in `filetype.vim`. For further reading  [`wikia`](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Filetype.vim), and [`:help filetype`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/filetype.txt.html).

Answer (score 8):

One thing I've noticed (and which seems to be the deal with your case as well) is that if you add new path on runtimepath, you should have the `filetype plugin on` done after updating the runtimepath.

For example, with the following vimrc, it would work fine:

```
set runtimepath+=/home/techgaun/fun/vim/mpc
filetype plugin indent on
```

And, if you run `:scriptnames`, you should see the ftdetect script loaded fine from your mpc plugin directory.

Answer (score 4):

In my case, vim appeared to not be sourcing the files under the `ftdetect` and `ftplugin` directories in the custom runtimepath. I tried putting the directories under my `.vim` folder:

```
.vim
├── autoload
│   └── mpc.vim
├── ftdetect
│   └── mpdv.vim
├── ftplugin
│   └── mpdv.vim
└── plugin
    └── mpc.vim
```

Now the script under `ftdetect` runs, as can be seen when I run `:scriptnames`:

```
1: /usr/share/vim/vimrc                                                                             
2: /usr/share/vim/vim74/debian.vim
3: ~/.vimrc
4: /usr/share/vim/vim74/filetype.vim
5: ~/.vim/ftdetect/mpdv.vim
6: /usr/share/vim/vim74/ftplugin.vim
7: /usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax/syntax.vim
8: /usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax/synload.vim
9: /usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax/syncolor.vim
10: ~/.vim/plugin/mpc.vim
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using vim's native `:packadd` functionality, note the following from `:h packadd`:

```
            If the filetype detection was not enabled yet (this
            is usually done with a `syntax enable` or `filetype on`
            command in your .vimrc file), this will also look
            for "{name}/ftdetect/*.vim" files.
```

So be sure to put any `packadd` calls before either `syntax enable` or `filetype plugin indent on`:

```
packadd! UltiSnips
" etc

filetype plugin indent on
```

This is similar to enabling `filetype` after manually modifying `runtimepath`.